# Android :android:configChanges value for Font Style change in Samsung Device

Tags: android, fonts, samsung-mobile, android-styles

Want to handle the [Font Style Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) myself.what will be the value?
Using the below values now.But the system kills the app and restarts[image].
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|fontScale|locale|layoutDirection|screenSize|screenLayout|mnc|mcc|uiMode|navigation|smallestScreenSize"

Thanks

Nitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, unfortunately. This seems to be using a different mechanism instead of configuration changes.

1. Setting up a service to listen for `android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` does not receive an Intent when a new font is selected in the dialog (but it does when the *font size* is changed, for example).
2. If it was handled as a configuration change, then the *activities* would be restarted, but not the app itself, as it's the case here.
3. Even if it were, the `android:configChanges` attribute does not accept arbitrary values, but only those listed in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config). So there would be no way to handle custom configuration changes.

If I had to guess, I'd say that Samsung's custom UI forcibly restarts all applications whenever the font is changed.

Comment: #1 we do get a android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED event from system on font style change, but the the intent is of null.So it cant be used as identifier.#2 agree.#3 yeah this is custom android:configChanges value of samsung and cant be used in manifest.But i remember we could have put custom value sometime no complile error.Correct me!.

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible, sorry. But maybe someone else will come up with a solution?

Comment: When font is changed, then activity is restarted,not the whole application.

Comment: in my case the app is crashing instead of restarting?