# Fragment.onCreateView called on configuration change?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here I wrote an simple activity and fragment. I changed orientation and since it's **configuration change** call so it called **Activity.onCreate()** again but why **Fragment.onCreateView()** again. Since I am not calling fragment child on configuration change call.

Here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_container);

        log("life_cycle_activity", "onCreate");

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {

            log("life_cycle_activity", "ohh..configuration changed");
            return;
        } else {

            launchChildFragment();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: android:configChanges not work on Settings->Display->FontStyle change**

Any suggestion how can prevent Fragment call on configuration change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are being recreated because the `savedInstanceState` parameter includes information on the "previous" Fragments present in the Activity. Check the implementation for the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method (and its corresponding logic in `onCreate()`) in [FragmentActivity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java) and you'll see where this information is stored and reloaded.

As for the "font size" configuration change, it doesn't seem to be possible (or at least I didn't find a way) to handle it with `android:configChanges`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21554419/82788).

As an aside though:

> Any suggestion how can prevent call for Fragment.onViewCreate on
>   configuration change.

Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Thanks @Matiash for info. I also found same analysis. Regards Fragment.onViewCreate prevention...I just wanted to avoid recreation call..But now I am pretty much clear about process.

Answer (score 1):

You can call:

> public void setRetainInstance (boolean retain)

with true value in your fragment onCreate - this will create the so called retained fragment,

or prevent activity config changes using:

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|locale|fontScale|mnc|mcc"

in manifest.

Comment: Hi, Thanks.but still Fragment method getting called..and regarding config para in manifiest..I am trying with settign->display->font style ..and I found nothing for it to handle in configChange. Your opinion please.

Comment: @Shubh you can also check if configchange is in progress: isChangingConfigurations() - since api11, look also into docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean), it clearly states: `Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (such as from a configuration change). `,also look into this detailed SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean